# Better Way To Expose Api for Asp.net Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, security, api

Need your help......
We are trying to expose API's for auction website(asp.net 4.0) using c# to allow our customer to create sale and add products from their own applications and let them published on our website.
I want to know that what will be best way to expose API in terms of security and compatibility with our technologies like PHP and Java,so that everyone can consume those API's.
If you can suggest any patterns or example references it would be great.

Comment: What's with all the inappropriate downvotes lately? Seems like a good question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a REST based web service. The benefit of REST based web service is that it can be easily consumed from large variety of languages. For security you can use basic authentication over ssl.

This can be your starting point [REST in Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529)

Answer (score 1):

Set up a web service.  `WSDL` is universal.  It will provide great flexibility while providing an abstract service your clients can call -- which is client independent.

Answer (score 0):

As George said, it sounds like you'll need a web service.  Look in to WCF.

Answer (score 0):

My first port of call is to use WCF. The interfaces it exposes are not .Net specific.

It is a huge subject to really sum up but as far as security is concerned there is nothing it cant do.

try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/your_first_WCF_service.aspx) as a starting point